# How do I get a FIDE ID?

Tags: fide, rating

I’m going to play in my first tournament which have said the following: “Those who don’t have a FIDE ID have to enroll FIDE ID registration under your own federation” and I don’t understand what they meant exactly.

How do I get a FIDE ID?

Answer (score 6):

Every national member federation has an IRO - International Rating Officer. It is their responsibility to register members of their federation with FIDE.

In the first instance you could find the email address and send them an email requesting that they register you with FIDE. The place to start is the [FIDE list of member federations](https://www.fide.com/directory/member-federations). If you go to this alphabetic list you see that by default it gives you, along with the list, the details of the first country in the list, Algeria. Scrolling down you see that the Rating Officer is Adnane Nesla and it gives his email address.

To find the IRO for England, where I live now, I click on "Europe" and then scroll down and click on "England". There I see that the IRO is Dave Clayton and his official email address is IRO@EnglishChess.org.uk.

In England the process for getting a FIDE ID for a tournament usually doesn't involve you personally emailing the IRO. Instead what you do is give your date of birth to the tournament director or arbiter and they pass your details on to the IRO on your behalf for registration.

Most federations will charge a higher membership fee if you also want to play in FIDE registered tournaments, particularly standard time control tournaments. This is because FIDE charges the member federations for rating standard rate games. FIDE do not charge for rating rapid and blitz so in those cases your federation may register you with FIDE for free. That is the case for ENG for blitz tournaments.

I should add one warning. You can also get an *unlicensed* FIDE ID by registering with FIDE's Online Arena. That allows you to play only in FIDE's online arena. It does not license you to play in FIDE rated over-the-board tournaments and if an arbiter or tournament organizer allows you to do that then the member federation will be fined by FIDE.

Comment: Few years ago, creating a FIDE was free, wasn't it? And there was a webpage to create id? I have completed a tournament and participated in another. But I am looking forward for my ID. After reading the answer, I have sent email to the federation (national).